# how to pass a string to a labes that contains special characters like % and !?

Tags: batch-file

Example:

```
call :my_label %%my!my%%myfolder%%folder!folder%%
:my_label
set my_local_var=%1
echo %my_local_var%
```

And I see no way of intact putting this string as local variable, is there a way to enable delayed expansion on a single percent variable ? Or any other way to prevent resolving variables in string ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you expect, but a general rule is to use `call` with references not with values, as some values can't be transported at all.

So you could use something like this.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "myString=%%my^!%%folder^!folder"
call :my_label myString
exit /b

:my_label
set "temp=!%1!"
echo !temp!
exit /b
```